# HP Command View: Could not find authenticator for Security Domain

Tags: authentication, storage, hp

I have some HP EVA storage arrays. They are monitored via Command View - the HP management product.

Of 8 management servers, a grand total of one will not let me log in using 'domain' credentials - in the logs, the following error message is generated:

```
DOMAINNAME\service_acc, 3248, 4252, 1, DomainCommServiceImpl, 661, Could not find authenticator for security domain DOMAINNAME
```

However, I *can* use the same account, provided I omit the 'DOMAINNAME\' prefix. It fails to authenticate as a local user, and falls back to using the domain user. I'm trying to fix this, because I want to use a single account, and don't want to have failed authentication attempts filling my logs.

My other 7 hosts do *not* have this problem, and as far as I'm aware the OS build is identical. I *think* this may be related to the installation process of CommandView. When I am trying to configure the 'Management Group' it only lists the local hostname under 'OS Security Domains'. Where my other management stations include a full list of all my domains.

So what I'd like to know - does anyone know of how I can get Command View to rediscover the OS Security domains? Does it require a reinstall/rebuild? It feels like something that should be simpler than that, but I'm having difficulty with digging through the documentation.

Comment: Is `DOMAINNAME` the NetBIOS name for the domain? If so, try with the domain FQDN

Comment: It is, yes. Have tried FQDN, and get the same result.